# Ocultar mostrar divs en JQUERY+PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Hola estoy intentando mostrar una tabla una vez completo dos campos pero antes dicha tabla la oculto con jquery y cuando le doy al boton para que pase por post quiero mostrar dicha tabla y ocultar los campos previos pero no me funciona. Los oculta de inicio, pero al ejecutar el check no muestra la tabla.

Añado tabla

**PHP-HTML**

```
echo "<table class='mytable' border-bottom:1px solid #A9A9A9;'>";
 echo "<div id='caja_trabajador_inn'>";
  echo "<div class='caja'>
           <select name='operari_sel' id='operari_sel'>
           <option value='default'>Selecciona un trabajador</option>";
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                     $id_operari=$row['tre_operario'];
                     $selected = ($_POST['operari_sel'] == $id_operari)? 'selected':'';
                     $nom_treballador = $row['tre_nom']." ".$row['tre_cognom'];
                     echo "<option value='$id_operari' ".$selected.">".$row["tre_operario"]." - ".$row["tre_nom"]." ".$row["tre_cognom"]."</option>";
          }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</div>";
      } else {
      echo "No hay trabajadores o hay un error";
    }
     echo "<div class='fecha_semana_class'>";
        echo "<input type='date' id='fecha_semana' name='fecha_semana' value='$fecha_introducir' required></input>";
      echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='fecha_semana_class'>";
    echo "<input type='button' id='btn_enviar_datos_treballador' name='btn_enviar_datos_treballador' value='Aceptar'></input>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "<table>";
```

**JQUERY**

```
    function check() {
      var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha_semana").value;
      var op = document.getElementById("operari_sel").value;
    if (fecha == "" || op == "default"){
      layer_show('','','Debes completar todos los campos.','');
      setTimeout(function(){
        layer_close();
      },10000);
      return false;
    }else {
      $("#tabla_pieles_inn").css("display", "block");
      $("#btn_cancelar_datos_treballador").css("display", "block");
      $("#btn_guardar_datos_treballador").css("display", "block");
      $("#caja_trabajador_inn").css("display", "none");
      save();
      return false;
    }
 }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#tabla_pieles_inn").css("display", "none");
      $("#btn_cancelar_datos_treballador").css("display", "none");
      $("#btn_guardar_datos_treballador").css("display", "none");
      $("#caja_trabajador_inn").css("display", "block");
      $("#btn_enviar_datos_treballador").click(function(){
     check();
     });
});

    function save(){
  section_post("#section-form","../basic/form_pieles_semanal.php",$('form#form_pieles').serialize());
}
```

Comment: Faltan algunos datos para reproducir tu problema. A saber: Elementos html: #tabla_pieles_inn, #btn_cancelar_datos_treballador, #btn_guardar_datos_treballador, #caja_trabajador_inn, #btn_enviar_datos_treballador (asi veremos como estan dispuestos en tu diseño), y luego las funciones layer_show y save (quizás el problema este alli, solo por si acaso)

Comment: Actualizado @masterguru

Comment: ¿Y la tabla donde esta definida?  no la veo

Comment: Ya la he insertado @masterguru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La tienes dentro del `'<div>'` con `id='caja_trabajador_inn'`, y por eso se esconde después de pulsar el botón, pues escondes toda esa capa, incluida la tabla.

Aquí he creado un boceto funcional de como deberia ser para que no ocurriera:

```js
 function check() {
   var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha_semana").value;
   var op = document.getElementById("operari_sel").value;
   if (fecha == "" || op == "default") {
     // layer_show('','','Debes completar todos los campos.','');
     //      setTimeout(function(){
     //        layer_close();
     //      },10000);
     return false;
   } else {
     $("#tabla_pieles_inn").css("display", "block");
     $("#btn_cancelar_datos_treballador").css("display", "block");
     $("#btn_guardar_datos_treballador").css("display", "block");
     $("#caja_trabajador_inn").css("display", "none");
     save();
     return false;
   }
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabla_pieles_inn").css("display", "none");
   $("#btn_cancelar_datos_treballador").css("display", "none");
   $("#btn_guardar_datos_treballador").css("display", "none");
   $("#caja_trabajador_inn").css("display", "block");
   $("#btn_enviar_datos_treballador").click(function() {
     check();
   });
 });

 function save() {
   // section_post("#section-form","../basic/form_pieles_semanal.php",$('form#form_pieles').serialize());
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='caja_trabajador_inn'>
  <div class='caja'>
    <select name='operari_sel' id='operari_sel'>
      <option value='default'>Selecciona un trabajador</option>
      <option value='1'>operario nom cognom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='fecha_semana_class'>
    <input type='date' id='fecha_semana' name='fecha_semana' value='' required>
  </div>
  <div class='fecha_semana_class'>
    <input type='button' id='btn_enviar_datos_treballador' name='btn_enviar_datos_treballador' value='Aceptar'>
  </div>
</div>
<table id="tabla_pieles_inn" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>columna tabla pieles</td>
      <td>columna tabla pieles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Básicamente la he sacado de ese **div**, como puedes ver. (He desactivado las llamadas javascript que no eran necesarias o que no podian ejecutarse bien por falta de más código, pero no son cruciales para esta respuesta, donde lo único que debes hacer en tu código real es sacarlo de ese **div**.)

Comment: El problema es que si lo hago así quitando el save() no me envia los POST, mi intencion es que se envie el formulario al darle al botón de aceptar por operario y fecha que se envie el formulario y se muestre la tabla @masterguru

Comment: En la parte final de mi respuesta, después del código, he explicado que he desactivado cosas de tu javsacript para realizar este ejemplo solamente, tu no tienes que hacerlo en el tuyo para nada.  Sino no podia ponerte el ejemplo aqui porque daria errores de javascript.  Lo único que tienes que hacer en tu caso real es sacar la tabla del div con el id `caja_trabajador_inn` y nada más.

Comment: No te dediques tan solo a copiar y pegar respuestas, **léete** las explicaciones, que tambien cuestan un trabajo y son para que aprendas

Comment: Si lo leí y lo entendí, y no copie y pegue, simplemente me gustaria saber cómo podria hacerlo porque con el check() envio el formulario para que se pasen los datos por post, y con lo que tengo es como que reinicio el formulario entonces como que no funciona por si me podias hechar una mano @masterguru

Comment: Vale, entiendo, pero eso es otro problema, que no puedo ayudarte si no pones lo que hace la función `section_post`, la cual pensé que enviabas por ajax, pero tal como me estas contando estas enviandola de alguna forma que hace que se recarge la pagina y se pierda el efecto logrado en esta respuesta... deberias abrir otra pregunta explicando eso y poniendo el código de esa función o directamente intentar que esa funcion sea por ajax o fetch o similar

Comment: De acuerdo ahora lo pongo, gracias y losiento @masterguru

Comment: Crea una nueva pregunta mejor, porque son temas distintos... en esta respuesta he solucionado una cosa, en la nueva alguien (o yo mismo) te ayudaran a solucionar la petición de esa funcion... no se aceptan preguntas con varios temas a la vez